# What is the recommended value of auto.leader.rebalance.enable property

Tags: apache-kafka

I am setting a kafka cluster and would like to know what is the recommended value of auto.leader.rebalance.enable property ?
kafka default value is true. is it ok to leave it as default ? can kafka default value cause any issue ?

Kafka version i am using is 2.5.0

Answer (score 8):

For the most part, I think it's sensible to leave `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` set to `true`, but I wanted to share a possible reason for keeping it disabled:

I experienced a production issue where a new broker was brought online. It had *lots* of data to replicate from other brokers/topics. Some of those topics had a small amount of data and some were quite massive. This caused the newly onlined broker to catch up on replication for smaller topics very quickly, and since `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` was set to `true`, it became a leader for some partitions on these topics. Meanwhile, because the broker was still catching up on replication for the topics with a lot of data, the broker's NIC was fully saturated, causing producers/consumers to time out on reads/writes from those topics/partitions that the broker was already a leader for.

For our particular setup, we decided that it's better to keep `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` set to `false`, then manually bring the brokers into balance by calling the `kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh` script only after verifying that it is in-sync with all the necessary topics/partitions. An alternative solution is to leave `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` set to `true`, but to set `leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds` to a less aggressive value so that a newly onlined broker isn't elected as a leader too eagerly.

For reference, I am using Kafka 2.6.

Comment: Yes, this echos what I have experienced in Kafka 3.3.1.  Namely that during a broker restart (for upgrade or change in configuration, ...) that it will attempt to rebalance the partition leaders while the broker is coming back up.  For me, this manifested in several topic-partitions immediately going into under-min-isr state.  the cluster was 100% current and in-sync before I started, only 1 broker was restarted, replication factor was 3, min.isr was 2.  leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds was set to 3600 and yet it attempted rebalance as soon as the broker was restarted.

Comment: @JimC: Were you able to solve this somehow ?

I'm experiencing a similar case where I tried to have a readinessCheck to actually check for the "replica imbalance" and only make the new restarted broker to be ready when the imbalance is zero. Even with that, we have producers/consumers timing out after the second broker restart..

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` option as default don't cause any issue, much for the contrary: it allows the load on the cluster to be evenly balanced between brokers.

Answer (score 0):

`auto.leader.rebalance.enable` is the broker config which aims towards achieving this

**All the broker should have even distribution of the number of partitions in terms of leader and follower.**

If you look at the documentation, it is described as

> Enables auto leader balancing. A background thread checks the
> distribution of partition leaders at regular intervals, configurable
> by `leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds`. If the leader imbalance
> exceeds `leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage`, leader rebalance to
> the preferred leader for partitions is triggered.

There could be multiple reasons by which the load on one broker might increase and it may happen that this broker becomes the leader for more partitions as compared to other brokers in the cluster. This particular config helps you in balancing this uneven load created.

> is it ok to leave it as default?

In my opinion **yes**, since it tries to balance the uneven load created. This is why as you noticed the default is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

> All the broker should have even distribution of the number of partitions in terms of leader and follower.

A caveat to answer from @ajay-kr-choudhary: Kafka (2.5-2.8, maybe for 3.x too) will not change the preferred broker leaders for each partition. The preferred broker is the first one listed in the partition -> broker assignments. If that list does not distribute the preferred brokers evenly, `auto.leader.rebalance.enable` nor `kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh` will redistribute leaders. You must do that yourself with `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` to change the preferred broker.